# Form to Ajax to PHP for Insert into SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, ajax, forms

I have tried very hard to get a simple working model of this to function. My actual Site is larger, but I've dumbed down the scripting to make things simple (and troubleshoot).

I keep getting "500" errors when I click to send the Form through, and I've been unable to figure out what I've been doing wrong. 
(I've set up a simple database to capture just this one item).

(The PHP file is named "sample2.php" within the same directory as html is in.)

A screenshot of my database:

[image: database screenshot]

My HTML File:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div name="maindiv" id="maindiv">
            <span>sample1:</span> <input id="sample1" name="sample1" width="300px" type="text" value="sample1text" /><br />
        </div>

        <input type="button" name="sendit" value="Do it" id="sendit"/> 

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#sendit").on("click", function() {
                var fieldvalue = [];

                $('#maindiv input').each(function() { 
                    fieldvalue.push([this.id, $(this).val()]); 
                });

                console.log(fieldvalue);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "sample2.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(fieldvalue),
                    success: function() {
                        alert("worked");
                    }
                });
            });     
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my PHP file:

```
<?
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=trialdb;host=extoleducation.ipagemysql.com","username","password");

    $id = $_POST['sample1'];

    $query->bindValue(':sample1', $sample1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sampletable (sampleline) VALUES (:sample1);";

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    if($statment = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $statment->execute();
        $statment->closeCursor();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have two prepares one after the other?

Comment: And `$query->bindValue` is coming before you even do `$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);`

Comment: oh, that must have been an accident. thank you!

Comment: so place the line " $query->bindValue " after the line " $query = $pdo->prepare($sql); "?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't answered why you have two prepares with the same sql statement. You only need one.

Comment: I'm still struggling to learn properly how to use SQL; this was a mistake. I am trying to create a functional 'cycle', so that I can build from here. I should remove the initial " $query = $pdo->prepare($sql); " shouldn't I?

Comment: I will answer, it's hard to comment it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP seems to be mixed up. For simplicity, try just doing this:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=extoleducation.ipagemysql.com;dbname=trialdb","username","password");

if(isset($_POST['sample1'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `sampletable` (`sampleline`) VALUES (:sample1)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    # I find binding values much easier just doing the array into the execute
    # If you get it working like this and really want to go back and try
    # bindValue(), you can
    $query->execute(array(':sample1'=>$_POST['sample1']));
}
```

This is as basic as it gets. If you can get this to work, then you just kind of build off of it. You may want to `try`/`catch` `PDOException`s if you want to troubleshoot any unforeseen sql errors.

For testing pursposes, I would be tempted to not send json, that way you can more-easily troubleshoot your php from the `console.log()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendit").on("click", function() {
        // If you are not serializing, I would do an object, not array
        var fieldvalue = {"action":"submit"};
        // Loop through and save names and values
        $('#maindiv input').each(function(k,v) { 
            fieldvalue[$(v).attr('name')] = $(v).val();
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "sample2.php",
            type: "POST",
            // Try just sending object here instead of json string
            data: fieldvalue,
            // On the success, add the response so you can see
            // what you get back from the page
            success: function(response) {
                // Do a check to see if you get any errors back
                console.log(response);
                // This has minimal value because it is only telling you
                // that the ajax worked. It's not telling you anything from the
                // response of the page
                alert("worked");
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

Comment: For multiple fields/values, do I nest the 'isset' within if statements, or can I throw them into the same isset() with comma's? Or may I simply pass an array of them all?

I'm going to have 12 fields in the live version. 
Thank you so much! I'm going to give this a go.

Comment: You just check for one parameter really, but you can pass a full array of values into the `execute()`

Comment: I made an update for the ajax. You may want to try it. If you do, then on your php just `print_r($_POST);` to make sure the page is getting what you are expecting. That will then show up in the `console.log` from the ajax success.

Comment: I have been able to get an alert! Thank you, so close! It does say "empty string" however... Please can you help me to get it to pass the value through? Picture: http://extoleducation.ipage.com/extol/test/examplePic.png

Here is a look at the SQL dBase when I've performed this, which is 'empty': http://extoleducation.ipage.com/extol/test/sqlPic.png

Comment: Did you change the ajax like I suggested? Also did you add `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Actually, let me fix your first part. I think it should be something other than what you have.

Comment: I did copy directly, but didn't yet change the print_r($_POST); no, sorry.. I have it saved here, if you wish to run it yourself, if this helps: http://extoleducation.ipage.com/extol/test/sample8.html

Comment: Alright, see my change in the jQuery. Do the `print_r($_POST);` then look at the console to see if it prints out the post

Comment: This is now fully functional. Thank you, Rasclatt. I (embarrasingly) admit to having spent a few dozen hours on just getting this already written code to function. THANK YOU!

Comment: Well, just a tip, I don't know what you do to troubleshoot but you should start off just getting something simple to work like I showed you. Then you know that functions, move on to the next small task and when that small task works, you know to move to the next small task. That way you don't move on to the next task without knowing other parts are working. If it was me, I would have done the php first to make sure it works. Then I would have done the ajax in it's most simple form. Then if that worked I would change it to use/send json (if required).

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you build in little chunks, that way you will always know that if something stops working, it's the last thing you are working on. If you do a whole set-up then try it when you are done, you will not know where exactly the problem is because it may be the php or a part of the js, or whatever. Anyway, you will save yourself a lot of overall work doing it this way.

Comment: I can agree with that. I will take this step-by-step sequencing to heart, and utilize this concept in my Scripting in the years to come.

 I am experienced in jQuery and HTML and CSS and JavaScript, but need to learn better how to PDO/PHP. This working model will set me on my way into the future. You have done amazing work for this, I am -so- appreciative! 
Two BIG thumbs up Stack Overflow.
and Three BIG thumbs up for you, Rasclatt!