# onclick display the value of MySQL fetch echo on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that has a `loan_id` and when I fetch the info, it is ok. This problem is I need to click on the `loan_id` number then let it display result based on the `id` number.

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("select * from request, users where request.user_id = users.id and request.user_id = $user_id")  or die(mysql_error());
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";    
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    Print "<tr class='my_loans_tr'>"; 
    echo ("<td  id='demo' onclick='myfunction(this) class='weblex-show- detail' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalw'>"  .$info['loan_id'] . "</td> ");
    Print " <td class='admin_amount'>".$info['amount'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td class='admin_points'>".$info['points'] . "</td> ";   
    Print " <td class='admin_date'>".$info['req_date'] . " </td>"; 
    Print " <td class='admin_status'>".$info['status'] . " </td>"; 
    Print " <td class='admin_cancelled'>".$info['cancelled_loan'] . " </td></tr>"; 
    Print "</tr>"; 
}  
Print "</table>";  
?>
```

[image]

The number `146` `147` are loan id's, so basically what I need is to click on the id number then it passes me the id number (any number I click) so I can then run a new query based on the `loan_id`. Each `loan_id` has more info stored in another table. I'm using bootstrap modal, if that matters.

I tried JavaScript but the furthest I got was to alert the same id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo").click(function(){
            alert("get content.");
        });
    });
</script>
```

in the end i need the value in php so i can run other MySQL query,

Comment: Why you do not use a JOIN in your first query for get all data and so have not to do another query?

Comment: i thought of it, 2 different tables, request where loan_id  is created for each loan, collected(table2) loan id is here as well but has a field name collected so i can have loanid 147 and 1-10 collected id that belongs to loan_id 147, that must be toggle, cant have all the info visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but I think this is what you are looking for:

**/functions/getUserRequest.php**

*This is a function to clean up the request. Best to just include it on the page before using it. This is optional.*

```
<?php
function getUserRequest($con,$user_id)
    {
        # Since mysql_ is deprecated/removed from new version, I will use PDO
        # safely binding the value
        $query = $con->prepare("select * from request, users where request.user_id = users.id and request.user_id = :0");
        $query->execute(array(":0"=>$user_id));
        while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $row[] = $result;
        }

        return (isset($row))? $row : array();
    }
```

**/functions/connection.php**

*Here is the database connection which would use `define()` values for the connection credentials. This is optional, but should be implemented in a more complete fashion. `mysql_*` is removed in PHP7.*

```
function connection()
    {
        return new \PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }
```

**/index.php**

```
# Here you would add a config with DB defines and such
# Add the functions
include_once(__DIR__.'/functions/connection.php');
include_once(__DIR__.'/functions/getUserRequest.php');
# Create connection
$con  = connection();
?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
<?php
# Since Ids are supposed to be unique, you should make an auto-incrementer
$i = 0;
# Pass id here
foreach(getUserRequest($con,123) as $info) {
?>
    <tr class='my_loans_tr'>
        <?php
        /*
        ** Here is where the incrementing happens
        ** Also, pass the whole element to the js function
        */
        ?>
        <td  id='demo<?php echo $i ?>' onclick='myfunction(this)' class='weblex-show- detail' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalw'><?php echo $info['loan_id'] ?></td>
        <td class='admin_amount'><?php echo $info['amount'] ?></td> 
        <td class='admin_points'><?php echo $info['points'] ?></td>     
        <td class='admin_date'><?php echo $info['req_date'] ?></td> 
        <td class='admin_status'><?php echo $info['status'] ?></td>
        <td class='admin_cancelled'><?php echo $info['cancelled_loan'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Then your JS function would start:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(obj)
    {
        // This should get the value between the <td>Value</td>
        var getValue = obj.innerHTML;
        // You should then be able to use AJAX to retrieve data with
        // inner value (or however you want to use this value)...
        alert(getValue);
    }
</script>
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

Since you are trying to use jQuery now, you need to trigger your clicks on the class since your ids are all unique.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // You need to be listening for the click on the class "detail"
        $(".detail").click(function(){
            // This captures the current selected DOM object
            var obj      = $(this);
            // This will extract the value inside
            var objValue = obj.text();
            // This is where you send the data to a new page to get a response
            $.ajax({
                url: '/page/to/ajax/dispatcher.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'id':objValue
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    // You can see the response in your console log
                    console.log(response);
                    // To update your html, you can just receive it from
                    // your ajax dispatch page and place it into the modal (or wherever)
                    $('#myModalw').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks alot the js is what i needed the most, pdo i'm reading it, because i'm planning to start using it, currently working with mysql and mysqli

Comment: you read my mine, because i know i'm searching how to pass this value to a php varialble

Comment: You have to use Ajax, I would suggest using jQuery ajax, it's very straight-forward.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187747/form-to-ajax-to-php-for-insert-into-sql/39187810#39187810

Comment: if i may ask, can you provide me an example of usage, just learning jquery i did some tests but did not working

Comment: got the alert on jquery was missing ajax libs, now get the value and provide it to a php variable

Comment: Review my edit, if you find it's helped you, feel free to upvote my answer, I won't mind...

Comment: i changed di 'demo' to class='detail', and changed the url to mine where the bootstrap modal is but nothing happens, on the console log i got admin_user.php?id=22:279 Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick()

Comment: You should be able to keep your class name as you have it, `detail` is already part of the classes so you can keep the `weblex-show-` if you want. As for the function, remove the `onclick="myfunction(this)"` now, you don't need it anymore. `$(".detail").click(function(){` is now listening for the click so `onclick` is not necessary.

Comment: ok got it work if i set an alert i get the info, how do i manage the value to drop into the modal, the url does take it at the place but into modal, i'm i suppose to set java into the modal content

Comment: You place the response into a container in the modal, I assumed `$('#myModalw').html(response);` from my example. So if you want to place content into an element like `<div id="myModalw"></div>` then you use what I have (`$('#myModalw').html(response);`).

Comment: one question if i use coockie , in java <script>document.cookie = "var1=objValue";
</script> then elsewhere <?php 
   $phpVar =  $_COOKIE['var1'];
   echo  "$phpVar";
?>
   but i cant get the value im getting word it self instead of the value

Comment: Well, you are putting the cookie value in quotes, so that makes it a string. Try `document.cookie = objValue;`. I am not 100% sure you need to do this (set a cookie), but it's your app, so you have a good reason.

Comment: no, sorry my bad i do need it post and i know it works i just cant get to echo the result in the modal, i highly appreciate your assistance i got very far thanks to you

Comment: If you are getting the correct response back from your ajax, then you need to designate a spot in your modal to put the ajax response. Can you post the html of your modal html?

Comment: now i'm done is working just need some adjust but i got the value finally, thanks alot

Comment: i got everything on console, i can see it , now on /page/to/ajax/dispatcher.php isn't supposedly to show the element, i use echo but nothing, does this can reload the page, your help got me where i am now, but honestly i'm stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131939/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-walter-alexander).